# "PM : Resume disk failed" error

Tags: 10.04, power-management

I have noticed that this version 10.04, all installations that I do .... always shown this error:

"PM: Resume disk failed"

Mesage This is shown by the command:

```
dmesg | grep-i failed (if i want to test on your system)
```

I've done a search and I know that PM is related to hibernation of the system ...
Someone can tell me how to fix or tell me if this error has any impact on the system?

Thanks,
Fabio

Answer (score 1):

It just means that you DIDN'T resume from hibernation.  Ignore it ( unless you were TRYING to resume from hibernation ).